# Grouping list of object by a field & applying binary function in one of the field to reduce it by sum in one line of code using stream java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Let's take for an example I have list of transaction which contains txnId, paymentCode, amount. Output should be each payment code wise how much amount collected.

I tried to group it based on payment code as key, & list of amount for the payment code, but I am not able to reduce it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Payment {

    Integer txnId;
    String paymentCode;
    Integer amount;

    Payment(Integer txnId, String paymentCode, Integer amount) {
        this.txnId = txnId;
        this.paymentCode = paymentCode;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getPaymentCode() {
        return this.paymentCode;
    }

    public Integer getAmount() {
        return this.amount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Payment [txnId=" + txnId + ", paymentCode=" + paymentCode + ", amount=" + amount + "]";
    }

}

public class ListGroupingSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Payment> payments = new ArrayList<>();
        payments.add(new Payment(100, "GPAY", 100));
        payments.add(new Payment(101, "CC", 200));
        payments.add(new Payment(102, "PAYTM", 300));
        payments.add(new Payment(103, "GPAY", 400));
        payments.add(new Payment(104, "CC", 500));

        // @formatter:off
        Map<String, List<Integer>> paymentListByCodeAndAmount = payments.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Payment::getPaymentCode, Collectors.mapping(Payment::getAmount, Collectors.toList())));
        System.out.println(paymentListByCodeAndAmount);
        
        //System.out.println(paymentListByCodeAndAmount.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)));
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

Which gives the output of

```
{CC=[200, 500], GPAY=[100, 400], PAYTM=[300]}
```

But, expectation is

```
{CC=700, GPAY=500, PAYTM=300}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map<String, Integer> paymentListByCodeAndAmount = payments.stream()
  .collect(groupingBy(Payment::getPaymentCode, summingInt(Payment::getAmount)));
```

(with exactly your expected output)

[image]

Really, `summingInt` is a [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) where `groupingBy` will put every group, you can *"sum ints"* or whatever you want.

For example, if the group data is not directly integers, you can map:

```
Map<String, Integer> paymentListByCodeAndAmount = payments.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Payment::getPaymentCode, 
                mapping(p -> p.amount * p.txnId, 
                        summingInt(x -> x))));
```

readed as *"with payments as stream, grouping by payment code, take the product of the amount and the txnId and give me the sum total"*.

But, of course, exists millions of combinations, instead simply sum you could summarize (min, max, avg, ...) and do something with this:

```
Map<String, Double> paymentListByCodeAndAmount = payments.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Payment::getPaymentCode,
                collectingAndThen(summarizingInt(p -> p.amount * p.txnId),
                        IntSummaryStatistics::getAverage)));
```

readed as *"with payments as stream, grouping by payment code, summarize the product of the amount and the txnId and then give me the average"*.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Is there any alternative to it like BinaryOperator functional interface which can be customized? Asking just for understanding

Comment: I've updated my answers but the `Collectors` are really a **DSL** so there are millions of different possibilities.